# How can HTTP work over UDP (in the case of Google's QUIC protocol)?

Tags: web-server, http, tcp, socket, udp

Here is my understanding of how a client-server HTTP server works.

1. The client creates a **TCP** socket connection to connect to the server and sends data.
2. The server creates a **TCP** socket connection to listen for incoming requests.

So it looks like both the client and the server need to agree on the use of the `Transport protocol` to use (in this case TCP). But if we want a website to work over UDP/QUIC protocol then we need both the client and the server to create a **UDP** socket connection. *But some websites use TCP and others use UDP...*

So does it mean it would need to look like this?

```
if (URI == 'https://www.google.com') {
  // Website that works over UDP
  client.create.UDP.socket
  client.sendData

  server.create.UDP.socket
  server.receive.data
} else {
  // Website that works over TCP
  client.create.TCP.socket
  client.sendData

  server.create.TCP.socket
  server.receive.data
}
```

So the client needs to keep a record of which website uses TCP and which websites use UDP/QUIC and create that kind of socket to communicate with it?

Comment: Exactly where are you writing this piece of code? HTTP is implemented on TCP/IP but it also works over UDP and QUIC. You have to define the port for UDP protocol properly.

Comment: Well Google works on TCP port 443 and also on QUIC/UDP port 443 but how does it work?

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is an encoding for verbs and responses. It can run across any transport, TCP, QUIC, SCTP. QUIC is optimized for HTTP/2, but [it does work as a generic transport](https://datatracker.ietf.org/meeting/93/materials/slides-93-hopsrg-6).

A problem is that https:// URLs imply TCP, from a strict reading of [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230). So, the Alt-Svc header in an initial TCP response offers quic or upgrades to http 2 or 3. [curl's notes on HTTP Alternative Services](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2019/03/03/alt-svc-in-curl/) may be helpful.

So when running a web server with this QUIC thing, you still need to listen on TCP so user agents can upgrade. Not using it would not standards compliant and have implementation issues, per a [QUIC working group discussion](https://github.com/quicwg/base-drafts/issues/253).

Comment: For QUIC, itym HTTP/3

Comment: At the moment, Alt-Svc headers promoting QUIC could be "quic" or some draft of h3. Try reading the headers from Google services. The legacy of this contributes to the confusion of application versus transport.

Comment: I can't really make sense of  how that relates to the "QUIC is optimized for HTTP/2" claim.